# How to create .NET Core 3 (nightly build) app in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

so I know there is nightly SDK build available for .NET Core 3.0. I decided to give it a go as I will be doing some tutorials about this new framework.

I installed SDK and ASP.NET Core shared framework from

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/daily-builds.md

I also installed latest prerelease version of Visual Studio 2017.
The problem is VS does not have support for .NET Core 3 and gives me error ".NET Core 3 or newer projects are not available in this version of Visual Studio" (the same error also gives me latest official VS 2017, version 15.8.6)

My question is, how do I create new "Hello World" project targeted with this framework? Do I need to edit JSON or XML files manually to switch them to new framework?
Any help would be really, really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is valid and it is also high quality. To whom downvote this question, please explain why you downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create new project using the nightly build of .NET Core 3.0 is only applicable from command prompt, because the current .NET Core 3.0 SDK tooling doesn't support VS 2017 yet.

The rough plan is this: integration of .NET Core 3.0 tooling will be available in next release of VS 2017, the VS 2019.

As far as I know until October 2018, there are no definite plans from Microsoft to integrate .NET Core 3.0 into VS 2017 yet.

To try to list all available project templates on .NET Core 3.0, you could try `dotnet new` command like this:

```
dotnet new --list
```

Example:

```
dotnet new winforms -n "HelloWinforms"
```

Good luck and happy coding with .NET Core 3.0!

**NOTE:**

*Currently there is no guarantee that projects created using the current nightly build of .NET Core 3.0 be compatible when opened in VS 2017.*

Comment: Thanks! So only possible way of creating projects and editing the code is without VS? Manually editing using Notepad++ or similar?

Comment: @ZoranBošnjak yes, it requires manual editing like poke's answer above. But you have to _know_ .first the XML tag related to .NET Core 3.0 SDK project template. Manual editing is good for simple projects, but for complex scenario such as multiple .NET target, you have to be careful and dilligent.